# alpha setting in R geom_segment and ggmap seems not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

when setting alpha in geom_segment and ggmap, the segment suddently disappears.
The code below does not show the segment, but if I remove the alpha setting (commented line) the segment appears.

I am using:

- R version 3.2.4
- ggmap_2.6.1
- ggplot2_2.1.0

(I suspect the problem can be related to the version of the libraries)

Code:

```
bbox<-c(8.5,44.68,11.43,46.64);

start_lat<-c(bbox[2]);
start_lon<-c(bbox[1]);
end_lat<-c(bbox[4]);
end_lon<-c(bbox[3]);
w<-c(1);

amap <- c(bbox);
z<-data.frame(start_lon,start_lat,end_lon,end_lat,w);
amap.map = get_map(location = amap, maptype='terrain', color='bw');
xx = ggmap(amap.map, extent = 'device', legend='bottomright');
#xx = xx + geom_segment(data=z, aes(x=start_lon,y=start_lat,xend=end_lon,yend=end_lat, size=w, colour=w));
xx = xx + geom_segment(data=z, aes(x=start_lon,y=start_lat,xend=end_lon,yend=end_lat, alpha=0.5,size=w, colour=w));
xx
```

Comment: Maybe your device doesn't support transparency. Does  `plot(1:10,col="#FF0000B4",cex=2,pch=15,ty="l")` produce a plot with a line? What's the output of `.Device`?

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Your code produce a plot with a line.
I also tried to remove extent = 'device' from my code (I am new to R -- I really do not know what extent = 'device' implies) and now alpha setting works! The only glitch is that with extent = 'device' the legend appears ovelaid to the map, now it is outside. I will look for solutions
Thanks for the hint

Comment: I still still the segment after running your code. I am using ggmap_2.6     ggplot2_2.1.0